# Cell selection visiblity

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Hello everyone and thanks for helping me with my little issue.

I am building a database and I ran accross a problem. I am trying to make certain cells visible when a selection from a drop down menu is chosen.

So for instance I want to choose `Main wheel`, then I only want `osi313` to be visible and `osi314` to be hidden.

My coding for this is below. But for whatever reason when I select `Main wheel` it doesn't do anything and when I select nose wheel it shows the right visible cell.

```vb
Private Sub Wheel_Type_Change()
    If Wheel_Type.Value = "Main Wheel" Then
        Me.OSI313_Label.Visible = True
        Me.OSI313.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.OSI314_Label.Visible = False
        Me.OSI314.Visible = False
    End If

    If Wheel_Type.Value = "Nose Wheel" Then
        Me.OSI314_Label.Visible = True
        Me.OSI314.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.OSI313_Label.Visible = False
        Me.OSI313.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code to allow for the fields to work. When I make test assets and the fields with info, I want the fields to be active when I go through the records. Under wheel type the type says Nose Wheel for instance. but if the previous record was a main wheel then the osi314 field wont be visible. I want to make the record to show the approriate fields without having to switch the drop down menu.

```
Private Sub Wheel_Type_Change()
If Wheel_Type.Value = "Select Type" Then
    Me.OSI314_Label.Visible = False
    Me.OSI314.Visible = False
    Me.OSI313_Label.Visible = False
    Me.OSI313.Visible = False
End If
If Wheel_Type.Value = "Main Wheel" Then
    Me.OSI313_Label.Visible = True
    Me.OSI313.Visible = True
    Me.OSI314_Label.Visible = False
    Me.OSI314.Visible = False
End If

If Wheel_Type.Value = "Nose Wheel" Then
    Me.OSI314_Label.Visible = True
    Me.OSI314.Visible = True
    Me.OSI313_Label.Visible = False
    Me.OSI313.Visible = False
End If
```

End Sub